# How to check if struct value exists within a struct

Tags: go

I am retrieving data from an API.
The struct output is :

```
 {
    StreamSpecification: {
      StreamEnabled: true,
      StreamViewType: "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
     },
    TableStatus: "ACTIVE"
  }
```

But if the API output does not have StreamSpecification in it, I am receiving the following error when trying to print the struct.

**panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=xxxxxxxx]**

How to check if the struct StreamSpecification exists in the value? Or how to fix the issue in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I would convert the struct into a map, and then check if the field you are interested in is in the map.

For example:

```
package main                                                                                                                       

import (                                                                                                                           
    "encoding/json"                                                                                                                
    "fmt"                                                                                                                          
)                                                                                                                                  

type MyStruct struct {                                                                                                             
    Name  string                                                                                                                   
    Score int                                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                                  

func main() {                                                                                                                      

    ms := MyStruct{Name: "Amy", Score: 34}                                                                                         

    var myMap map[string]interface{}                                                                                               
    data, _ := json.Marshal(ms)                                                                                                    
    fmt.Println(data)                                                                                                              

    json.Unmarshal(data, &myMap)                                                                                                   

    fmt.Println(myMap)                                                                                                             

    _, ok := myMap["Name"]                                                                                                         
    fmt.Printf("name is in myMap: %t\n", ok)                                                                                       

    _, ok = myMap["Location"]                                                                                                      
    fmt.Printf("Location is in myMap: %t\n", ok)                                                                                   

}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jjByob2XP6-)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're trying to access `StreamEnabled` or `StreamViewType` when you haven't first confirmed if `StreamSpecification` was provided in the JSON object.

Assuming you have the internal `StreamSpecification` as a reference to a struct, you need to ensure that `StreamSpecification` isn't `nil`:

```
if (instance.StreamSpecification == nil) {
    // StreamSpecification was not passed in the JSON.
}
```

Comment: I had tried that but i am getting a compilation error "cannot convert nil to type dynamodb.StreamSpecification" Here is the struct https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#StreamSpecification

Comment: Can you just include a [mcve] in your question - hard to diagnose if we can't see your actual code.